# How to share laptop internet to phone via bluetooth?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth, android

How do I make it so that my laptop, while connected to the wifi, will share it's internet connection to my Android phone via bluetooth? When I try to search for it, I keep getting solutions for the other way around.

**Just for clarification:** If my phone is connected to the wifi, it **can** share its internet connection to my laptop via bluetooth. There's no problem there. The one I need help with is the other way around.

Comment: See also: [Share internet connection from windows to android via bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/857066)